# Динамическое создание миниатюр

Tags: php

Сделал класс по примеру [урок](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=953). Вертикальную обрезает - супер, а горизонтальную - оставляет по бокам вертикальные черные полосы. В чем ошибка? Вот кусок кода расчета

```
$nw = 183*3;    // Ширина миниатюр
$nh = 106*3;    // Высота миниатюр
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
$wm = $this->getWidth()/$nw;
$hm = $this->getHeight()/$nh;
$h_height = $nh/2;
$w_height = $nw/2;
if($this->getWidth() > $this->getHeight()) {
 $adjusted_width = $this->getWidth() / $hm;
 $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
 $int_width = $half_width - $w_height;
 imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image,-$int_width,0,0,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
```

**UPDATE 2**
вот что получилось.

```
function my_center($w,$h)
{
    $src_w = $this->getWidth();
    $src_h = $this->getHeight();
    if ($src_w > $w || $src_h > $h) {
        if ($h > $src_h ) {
            $scale = $src_h / $h;
        } else {
            $scale = $src_w / $w;
        }
        $c_w = $scale * $w;
        $c_h = $scale * $h;
    } else {
        $c_w = $w;
        $c_h = $h;
    }
    $c_x = ceil(($src_w - $c_w) / 2);
    $c_y = ceil(($src_h - $c_h) / 2);

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopyresized($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, $c_x, $c_y, $w, $h, $c_w, $c_h);
$this->image = $new_image;

}
```

Comment: без кода, врядли кто сможет вразумительно ответить.

Comment: а куда можно залить код?

Comment: в тело вопроса, не думаю что его там много.

Comment: не то((( онон например с картинки 1200 на 1000 вырезает кусок по центру 183 на 106..а мне нужно чтоб картинка была все..не кусок по центра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы какую-то фигню делаете.

получить вышеуказанные размеры нам удастся не всегда, ибо все картинки будут иметь разную геометрию. посему у нас есть несколько вариантов решения

1. изменять размер только ширины или высоты, а второй размер высчитывать через пропорции.
2. изменять размер игнорирую пропорциии, в таком случае картинка может быть растянута.
3. изменять размер согласно пункту 1, лишнее обрезать.

определитесь что именно вам нужно и реализуйте это.

**UPDATE:**

> а можно пример кода с фокусом в центре?

как то так (дубль №2)

```
function gdlib_resize_image($src, $dst, $w, $h)
{
    $is = getimagesize($src);
    $src_ext = pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $dst_ext = pathinfo($dst, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    switch (strtolower($src_ext)) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg': $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); break;
        case 'gif': $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src); break;
        case 'png': $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src); break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    $src_w = $is[0];
    $src_h = $is[1];

    if ($w > $src_w || $h > $src_h) {
        if ($h > $src_h) {
            $scale = $src_h / $h;
        } else {
            $scale = $src_w / $w;
        }
    } else {
        if ($w > $h) {
            $scale = $src_w / $w;
        } else {
            $scale = $src_h / $h;
        }
    }
    $c_w = $scale * $w;
    $c_h = $scale * $h;
    $c_x = ceil(($src_w - $c_w) / 2);
    $c_y = ceil(($src_h - $c_h) / 2);

    $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $c_x, $c_y, $w, $h, $c_w, $c_h);
    imagedestroy($src_img);

    switch (strtolower($dst_ext)) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg': imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst); break;
        case 'gif': imagegif($dst_img, $dst); break;
        case 'png': imagepng($dst_img, $dst); break;
    }
    imagedestroy($dst_img);
    return file_exists($dst);
}
```

Comment: нужен как раз 3 вариант изменить размер по маленькой стороне а потом обрезать второй размер в нужные пропорции

Comment: я бы вам еще рекомендовал делать "обрезание" картинки с фокусом в центре, т.е обрезать края.

Comment: а можно пример кода с фокусом в центре?

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: а функцию imagecopyresized можна заменить на imagecopyresampled ? у меня просто это класс, и функция загрузки и сохранения сделаны отдельно.

Comment: можно, только я не понимаю причем тут класс к imagecopyresized

Comment: А самому допилить ? Шо ж это такое то, я хочу то то и тото, дайте мне готовое решение ... и не стыдно вам ?

зы: обновил ответ

Comment: Виноват.. не работало из-за строчки
if ($w > $src_w || $h > $src_h) {
заменил на  if ($src_w > $w || $src_h > $h) {
спасибо, сейчас как раз то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Вы с самого начала делаете миниатюру размером 183х3 на 106х3, а вам бы сначала посмотреть она вертикальная или нет. И тогда поменять w и h местати просто.

**Дополнено.**

Например, себе делал подгонку рисунков до выбранных масштабов.

```
$ico=imageCreateFromjpeg($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']);
$iheight = imagesy($ico);
$iwidth  = imagesx($ico);
$w=640; // высота
 $h_max=480; //ширина
  if ($iwidth>$w) {
$h=$iheight/($iwidth/$w);
if ($h>$h_max) {
$h=$h_max;
$w=$iwidth/($iheight/$h_max);
}
$ico_file=imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);  imagecopyresampled($ico_file,$ico,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$iwidth,$iheight);
```

Comment: Вертикальные работают нормально

    elseif(($this->getWidth() < $this->getHeight()) || ($this->getWidth() == $this->getHeight())) {     
  $adjusted_height = $this->getHeight() / $wm;
  $half_height = $adjusted_height / 2;
  $int_height = $half_height - $h_height;
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image,0,-$int_height,0,0,$nw,$adjusted_height,$this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());

Comment: например себе делал подгонку рисунков до выбранных маштабов.<pre>
$ico=imageCreateFromjpeg($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']);
$iheight = imagesy($ico);
$iwidth  = imagesx($ico);
$w=640; // высота
 $h_max=480; //ширина
  if ($iwidth>$w) {
$h=$iheight/($iwidth/$w);
if ($h>$h_max) {
$h=$h_max;
$w=$iwidth/($iheight/$h_max);
}
$ico_file=imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h); imagecopyresampled($ico_file,$ico,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$iwidth,$iheight);
</pre>

Comment: У меня проблема жестко забиты пропорции готовой картинки и его сильно перекашивает когда нет пропорций

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить

```
 imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image,-$int_width,0,0,0,$nw,$nh,$this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
```

Плюс еще смущает -$int_width, по идее если делается превьюшка, то должно быть:

```
 imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image,0,0,0,0,$nw,$nh,$this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());

$nw = 183*3;    // Ширина миниатюр
$nh = 106*3;    // Высота миниатюр

$wm = $this->getWidth()/$nw;
$hm = $this->getHeight()/$nh;
$h_height = $nh/2;
$w_height = $nw/2;
if($this->getWidth() > $this->getHeight()) {
 $adjusted_width = $this->getWidth() / $hm;
 $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
 $int_width = $half_width - $w_height;
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($adjusted_width, $nh);//переносим создание картинки сюда
 imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image,0,0,-$int_width,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
```

Comment: -$int_width - это смещение по горизонтали...это работает правильно..я так подоздреваю неправильно работает$adjusted_width Вот что получается http://i071.radikal.ru/1109/a8/7db99a1d3d47.jpg если убрать -$int_width черная область справа будет вся

Comment: чтобы было понятней, когда вы создаете превьюшку ($new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);) вы задаете ей и высоту и ширину, и если в последствии меняете ширину($adjusted_width), то и получаете полосы и не верное обрезание по ширине. если ширина рисунка на выходе должна быть $adjusted_width то лучше сделать imagecreatetruecolor($adjusted_width, $nh);

Comment: я ей создаю нужный мне размер. на 3 умножаю для примера.почему тогда вертикальные правильно работает.

Comment: вообще бред получился http://i002.radikal.ru/1109/9c/5db0a99ada26.jpg

Comment: -$int_width надо перенести, я так понимаю это поправка к исходному изображению, а не к выходящему.
 imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image,0,0,-$int_width,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());

Comment: не помогло..результат не изменился..мне кажется в расчетах где-то ошибка..не могу найти..